# Retrieving jq results as one list object, vs a stream of members

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, stream, jq

Hi i am trying in shell script to get a list of consul service tags for myApp passing nodes, using jq.

when i have something like this..

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/health/service/myApp?dc=a&passing=true' \
  | jq '.[].Checks[1].ServiceTags[]'
```

output is..

```
"a"
"b"
"c"
"d"
```

I want to know if i could get it as a list. I want the output in this way..

```
 ["a","b","c","d"]
```

can you please suggest options..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
jq '.[].Checks[1].ServiceTags[]'
```

Try

```
jq '[.[].Checks[1].ServiceTags[]]'
```

The extra `[]` instruct jq to collect the values into an array.
See [Array construction: []](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Arrayconstruction:[]) in the jq Manual.

Comment: If that solves your problem please accept it as answered or wait for other explanations.